# I have set up Spamassassin. Only outgoing emails are scanned by spamassassin and not incoming ones

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I have set up spamassassin with postfix. The problem is I tried testing the spamassassin default filter by sending the GTUBE spam test email from gmail to my mail server. Spamassassin is not even checking that email or for that case, any incoming email. But only the outgoing emails are being checked by spamassassin and if I try to send the GTUBE test email to my gmail account from my server, spamassassin blocks it. I have started from scratch and each and every time this same problem persists. Please help

My postfix master.cf file:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
 -o content_filter=spamassassin
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
 -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e  
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

My spamassassin config:

```
# /etc/default/spamassassin
# Duncan Findlay

# WARNING: please read README.spamd before using.
# There may be security risks.

# If you're using systemd (default for jessie), the ENABLED setting is
# not used. Instead, enable spamd by issuing:
# systemctl enable spamassassin.service
# Change to "1" to enable spamd on systems using sysvinit:
ENABLED=1

# Options
# See man spamd for possible options. The -d option is automatically added.

# SpamAssassin uses a preforking model, so be careful! You need to
# make sure --max-children is not set to anything higher than 5,
# unless you know what you're doing.

OPTIONS="--create-prefs --max-children 5 --username spamd --helper-home-dir /home/spamd/ -s /home/spamd/spamd.log"

# Pid file
# Where should spamd write its PID to file? If you use the -u or
# --username option above, this needs to be writable by that user.
# Otherwise, the init script will not be able to shut spamd down.
PIDFILE="/var/run/spamd.pid"

# Set nice level of spamd
#NICE="--nicelevel 15"

# Cronjob
# Set to anything but 0 to enable the cron job to automatically update
# spamassassin's rules on a nightly basis
CRON=1
```

My spamasssassin log:

```
Mon Aug 12 13:23:47 2019 [16867] info: logger: removing stderr method
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: zoom: able to use 346/346 'body_0' compiled rules (100%)
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783 (running version 3.4.2)
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: spamd: server pid: 16898
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 16900
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 16901
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: prefork: child states: SI
Mon Aug 12 13:23:48 2019 [16898] info: prefork: child states: II
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:58002 to port 783, fd 5
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: spamd: processing message  for spamd:1001
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-467.awsdns-58.com
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1622.awsdns-10.co.uk
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1158.awsdns-16.org
Mon Aug 12 13:25:13 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-552.awsdns-05.net
Mon Aug 12 13:25:14 2019 [16900] info: spamd: identified spam (998.9/5.0) for spamd:1001 in 0.3 seconds, 1610 bytes.
Mon Aug 12 13:25:14 2019 [16900] info: spamd: result: Y 998 - ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,GTUBE,HTML_MESSAGE,TVD_SPACE_RATIO,TVD_SPACE_RATIO_MINFP scantime=0.3,size=1610,user=spamd,uid=1001,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=58002,mid=,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Mon Aug 12 13:25:14 2019 [16898] info: prefork: child states: II
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:58122 to port 783, fd 5
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: spamd: processing message  for spamd:1001
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-467.awsdns-58.com
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1622.awsdns-10.co.uk
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1158.awsdns-16.org
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-552.awsdns-05.net
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: spamd: clean message (-1.1/5.0) for spamd:1001 in 0.2 seconds, 1573 bytes.
Mon Aug 12 13:42:12 2019 [16900] info: spamd: result: . -1 - ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE scantime=0.2,size=1573,user=spamd,uid=1001,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=58122,mid=,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Mon Aug 12 13:42:13 2019 [16898] info: prefork: child states: II
Mon Aug 12 14:35:03 2019 [16900] info: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:58214 to port 783, fd 5
Mon Aug 12 14:35:03 2019 [16900] info: spamd: processing message  for spamd:1001
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1622.awsdns-10.co.uk
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-467.awsdns-58.com
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-552.awsdns-05.net
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns-1158.awsdns-16.org
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: spamd: clean message (-1.1/5.0) for spamd:1001 in 0.3 seconds, 1501 bytes.
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16900] info: spamd: result: . -1 - ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE scantime=0.3,size=1501,user=spamd,uid=1001,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=58214,mid=,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Mon Aug 12 14:35:04 2019 [16898] info: prefork: child states: II
```

The lines in the spamassassin log which tells that its a spam, those test spam emails(GTUBE email) were sent from my server.

As it can  be seen, spamassassin is only scanning outgoing emails and not incoming ones

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Please provide your actual postfix configuration, so we can take a look at it. Without it, it it's just blind guessing.

Comment: Added postfix master.cf spamassasin config and spamassassin log file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are filtering in `submission` entry of master.cf file, your mails are only checked on when a client is sending a mail. To check in incoming, you must define in `smtp` section of your master.cf.

Do not forget to check the `main.cf` file too !

Comment: so should I move
 -o content_filter=spamassassin line above 
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd line?

Comment: yes ! It will be in "smtp" section used for incoming mails, on port 25

Comment: I use SSL IMAP port 993. So will it work with SSL too?

Comment: I use SSL IMAP port 993 and TLS 587. So will it work too?

Comment: IMAP has nothing to do with SMTP. IMAP allow the user to get the mails stored in the server, SMTP allow to send mail to another server. Port 587 is submission so you already configure it. You may look at SMTPS (port 465) too...

Comment: Thanks! Just now changed the config and it works! Thank you so much!